# Using distinct() function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I'm working with a large dataframe containing longitude and latitude coordinates, each in a different column. I would like to remove every duplicated row only if it has the same longitude AND latitude. Will this solve the problem?

```
distinct(dat, dat$longitude, dat$latitude, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm removing rows that have only matching longitudes and different latitudes or the other way around.

Comment: You can do `distinct(dat, longitue, latitude, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: Per akrun's suggestion, anytime you're working within `dplyr` (and other tidyverse package) functions, you generally should not reference the frame variable itself. What this means is that in your `distinct(dat, dat$longitude)`, remove all references to `dat$`, so you get what akrun suggested. While it works just fine without that change in this example, if you do anything that changes the order, value, or size of the data in preceding `dplyr` verbs (e.g., `filter`, `group_by`, `mutate`), then the data that you want to use is different than what `dat$...` will give you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean `dplyr::distinct`, it's pretty easy to test this with a toy example:

```r
dat <- data.frame(longitude = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                  latitude = c(10, 11, 12, 10, 12, 10))
dat
#>   longitude latitude
#> 1         1       10
#> 2         2       11
#> 3         3       12
#> 4         1       10
#> 5         2       12
#> 6         3       10

dplyr::distinct(dat, longitude, latitude, .keep_all = TRUE)
#>   longitude latitude
#> 1         1       10
#> 2         2       11
#> 3         3       12
#> 4         2       12
#> 5         3       10
```

You can see that it has only removed the row where *both* variables were repeated.

Incidentally, you might want to look again at the result of your own code on this dataset:

```
distinct(dat, dat$longitude, dat$latitude, .keep_all = TRUE)
#>   longitude latitude dat$longitude dat$latitude
#> 1         1       10             1           10
#> 2         2       11             2           11
#> 3         3       12             3           12
#> 4         2       12             2           12
#> 5         3       10             3           10
```

As Akrun pointed out, you don't want to include the `dat$` when using tidy evaluation.